# html reset doesn't work with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm having a drop down with onChange event which will call the javascript method.

but when I change to some value and clicking reset , its reset to orignial value, but the onChange javascript event is not calling.

```
<select onChange="method1()">
<option>....
</select>

<input type="reset" value="reset" />
```

After click the reset button, the value is setting to old value but the onChange event is not working...

Comment: Can you post your code snippet / info that can help us help you?

Comment: Can you post javascript method too?

Answer (score 4):

I believe you should be using the [onchange](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp) event. I've never heard of the `valueChange` event.

**Updated for question edit:**

You will need to add a method to the `onreset` event of your `form` tag in order for you to run Javascript when your reset button is clicked. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_form_onreset.asp) for more info. This is a simple example, which requires two Javascript functions, `formReset` and `selectChanged`.

```
<form onreset="formReset">
    <select id="s" onchange="selectChanged">
        <option>Hello</option>
        <option>World</option>
    </select>
    <input type="reset" />
</form>
```